# monty hall induction

Tags: induction, monty-hall

Recently, I learned how to solve the Monty hall Problem through Bayes' theorem. Since this is a direct way of proof, I was interested whether the problem can be solved by mathematical induction. However, I couldn't reach a conclusion, and I want to know two things:

1) Is it impossible to prove the Monty Hall problem through mathematical induction?

2) If then, why?

(My Maths is not that good so please explain it in an easy way!)

Comment: What kind of Monty Hall problem? The generalised case with $n$ doors?

Comment: The classic Monty Hall problem is fairly finite, so I don't see how you would use induction. I'm sure there is some way to force induction into it, but like many bounded problems, it probably doesn't need it.

Comment: @ParclyTaxel Yes